# Assemble - how to generate thumbnails?

Tags: assemble

Would it be possible for Assemble to generate thumbnails from a source file - or is it out of the scope of assemble, if so, could someone suggest an alternate path?

Comment: I'd like to help you but it's unclear what you mean. thumbnails are images. thumbnail placeholders could be images, CSS or javascript. do you want to generate HTML for something like this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails?

Comment: No I want to take one image and generate multiple versions of that image in various sizes, crops and ratios.

Comment: oh, okay. that's not what assemble does, sorry. (fwiw, I'm not the one that downvoted)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with Assemble, but maybe you can find what you are looking for in [gulp-image-resize](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-image-resize/).